# PHP extension installation mssql

Tags: php, installation

I am trying to install mssql extension on the RedHat linux server. I am unable to understand which path should be given in order to configure the extension. Code example below is something like this:

--with-mssql=/usr/local

What will be the path "/usr/local" in my case which path should I give over here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
PREPARE SOURCE CODE
step 1: download latest php version
step 2: un-tar the php source code
step 3: download latest freetds version
step 4: un-tar the freetds source code

INSTALL THE FREETDS
step 5: make sure there is a writable directory at /usr/local/freetds
step 6: "cd" to the freetds source directory
step 7: run "sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/freetds --enable-msdblib"
step 8: run "sudo make"
step 9: run "sudo make install"
step 10: run "touch /usr/local/freetds/include/tds.h" (add blank, but necessary files)
step 11: run "touch /usr/local/freetds/lib/libtds.a" (add blank, but necessary files)

INSTALL THE PHP
step 11: "cd" to the php source directory
step 12: run "sudo ./configure --disable-all --with-mssql=/usr/local/freetds"
step 13: run "sudo make"
step 14: run "sudo make install"
```

Comment: The configure script is looking for tds.h header file. Its trying to find this file in

--with-mssql=/usr/local/freetds/

/usr/local/freetds/include/tds.h
or
/usr/local/freetds/include/freetds/tds.h

Locate the tds.h file on your system and then set --with-mssql accordingly.